# Append hexadecimal to string on PHP

Tags: php, hex

I want to append hexadecimal value to a string or int value and return as hexadecimal.

```
$hexData = 0xA;
$str = 45;
```

or

```
$str = "45";
```

Result:

```
0xA45;
```

Comment: $hexData.$str should work

Comment: It return string data and I want hex.

Comment: What you want is not all that clear. Do you need to concatenate both variables but get the result as hexadecimal? Like [this](https://3v4l.org/mDU7c)?

Comment: Yeah, that's right but I want to send these data to serial port and it receives only hex data not string.

Comment: @VishalAnand how you get this `$hexData = 0xA;` value ?

Comment: A string is the only format where you will see your value in hex form. The other choice is an integer, which is always displayed as a regular number unless using `sprintf()` for example. So @Tarun's comment is right.

Answer (score -2):

fro merge two hexadecimal and string can use dechex() and hexdec() :

```
echo 0xA45; // print 2629
echo hexdec(dechex($hexData) . $str); // print 2629
```

Comment: Still you will get "0xA45" and I want only 0xA45, not with double quotes.

Comment: @VishalAnand how do you get this value? `$hexData = 0xA;`

Comment: This data (0xA) is hard-code. Only $str variable is going to vary.